# How to create a dynamic list of custom objects associated with a flag (boolean)?

Tags: java, android, collections

I am eventually fetching objects from my backend and I have to keep track of them. I need a collection where there are no duplicates, but every time I fetch the same object from the backend I get a new instance, so I must compare it's String key manually, I suppose.

Plus, these objects need a boolean associated with them, because they may be in this list and be "used" and I should know that later.

A typical scenario is that I have a list of 10 objecst in my collection and I fetch 8 new ones, and only 3 are new. I should add these 3 to these list and discard the 5 repeated ones.

I am about to start implementing a custom Collection for that. Is there any possibility to do it combining Pair with List, or maybe HashMap? I've been thinking on this and I couldn't come up with a conclusion.

Comment: use TreeSet (ordered set) and pass in your own comparator so u can handle duplicates https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I implemented a custom class with both a list of objects and an array with my booleans. Since I had to keep both list and array synchronized, I had to iterate this list on all steps.

This is my code:

```
public class PromoCollection {

    public static List<ParseObject> promotions = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

    public static List<Boolean> isTriggered = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public static void add(ParseObject newObj) {
        for (ParseObject p : promotions) {
            if (p.getObjectId().equals(newObj.getObjectId())) {
                return; // Object already in list, do not add
            }
        }
        promotions.add(newObj); // Add new object
        isTriggered.add(false); // And respective boolean
    }

    public static void remove(ParseObject obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < promotions.size(); ++i) {
            if (obj.getObjectId().equals(promotions.get(i).getObjectId())) {
                promotions.remove(i);
                isTriggered.remove(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void trigger(ParseObject obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < promotions.size(); ++i) {
            if (obj.getObjectId().equals(promotions.get(i).getObjectId())) {
                isTriggered.set(i, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isTriggered(ParseObject obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < promotions.size(); ++i) {
            if (obj.getObjectId().equals(promotions.get(i).getObjectId())) {
                return isTriggered.get(i);
            }
        }
        throw new ArrayStoreException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E) Try something with a set. It allows no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

In the class of your objects, override both `equals()` and `hashCode()` to specify when two instances of your class can be considered to be the same.

If you do this, you can simply throw them into a `HashSet` and it will make sure that no to elements in it are the same (by the definition that you provided in the overridden methods)

Take a look at this similar question:
[Implement equals with Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573055/implement-equals-with-set)